# mount HD with "special rights"

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, automount

I auto mount (on boot/startup) an external (USB) HD on my Ubuntu Server. But, my webserver must see, and have access to the filesystem on this HD. My System is `3.16.0-53-generic #72~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 >x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

At the moment I mount the HD with these settings:

```
/dev/sdb1   /media/MOUNTPOINT   ext4    defaults    0   0
```

I need rights for user "www-data". But, if I do this after automount, a error message comes up ...

> sudo -u www-data chown -R www-data:www-data /media/MOUNTPOINT
>   chown: der Eigentümer von »/media/MOUNTPOINT“ wird geändert: Vorgang nicht zulässig

translation: "**Operation not allowed.**"

How can I mount the whole HD for user "www-data"?

Comment: Practical solution #1: Do not change the mountpoint put put all data one level deeper.

Comment: You can write `LANG=C` before a command to get English output, e.g. for posting it here. Example: `LANG=C sudo -u www-data chown -R www-data:www-data /media/MOUNTPOINT`. Or you can write `LANG=C` as single command to set the terminal session language to English. It will go back to your default when you close the terminal window and open a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run chown as root user, as www-data is not allowed to change the owner of the files:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/MOUNTPOINT
```